# Using json_encode on objects in PHP (regardless of scope)

Tags: php, json, scope, redbean

I'm trying to output lists of objects as json and would like to know if there's a way to make objects usable to `json_encode`?  The code I've got looks something like

```
$related = $user->getRelatedUsers();
echo json_encode($related);
```

Right now, I'm just iterating through the array of users and individually exporting them into arrays for `json_encode` to turn into usable json for me.  I've already tried making the objects iterable, but `json_encode` just seems to skip them anyway.

*edit*: here's the var_dump();

```
php > var_dump($a);
object(RedBean_OODBBean)#14 (2) {
  ["properties":"RedBean_OODBBean":private]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "17972"
    ["pk_UniversalID"]=>
    string(5) "18830"
    ["UniversalIdentity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["UniversalUserName"]=>
    string(9) "showforce"
    ["UniversalPassword"]=>
    string(32) ""
    ["UniversalDomain"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["UniversalCrunchBase"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["isApproved"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["accountHash"]=>
    string(32) ""
    ["CurrentEvent"]=>
    string(4) "1204"
    ["userType"]=>
    string(7) "company"
  }
  ["__info":"RedBean_OODBBean":private]=>
  array(4) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "user"
    ["sys"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idfield"]=>
      string(2) "id"
    }
    ["tainted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["model"]=>
    object(Model_User)#16 (1) {
      ["bean":protected]=>
      *RECURSION*
    }
  }
}
```

and here's what json_encode gives me:

```
php > echo json_encode($a);
{}
```

I ended up with just this:

```
    function json_encode_objs($item){   
        if(!is_array($item) && !is_object($item)){   
            return json_encode($item);   
        }else{   
            $pieces = array();   
            foreach($item as $k=>$v){   
                $pieces[] = "\"$k\":".json_encode_objs($v);   
            }   
            return '{'.implode(',',$pieces).'}';   
        }   
    }
```

It takes arrays full of those objects or just single instances and turns them into json - I use it instead of json_encode.  I'm sure there are places I could make it better, but I was hoping that json_encode would be able to detect when to iterate through an object based on its exposed interfaces.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($related)` and `echo json_encode($related)`?

Comment: 'objects' by definition are not iterable.

Comment: By iterable, I mean that the objects implement the interface IteratorAggregate and that I can iterate over them with a simple foreach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In RedBeanPHP 2.0 there is a mass-export function which turns an entire collection of beans into arrays. This works with the JSON encoder..

```
json_encode( R::exportAll( $beans ) );
```

Comment: Also, in RB 2.0, if you cast a bean to a string you'll get the JSON representation.

Answer (score 167):

All the properties of your object are private.  aka... not available outside their class's scope.

#### Solution for PHP >= 5.4

Use the new `JsonSerializable` Interface to provide your own json representation to be used by `json_encode`

```
class Thing implements JsonSerializable {
    ...
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'something' => $this->something,
            'protected_something' => $this->get_protected_something(),
            'private_something' => $this->get_private_something()
        ];
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Solution for PHP < 5.4

If you do want to serialize your private and protected object properties, you have to implement a JSON encoding function *inside* your Class that utilizes `json_encode()` on a data structure you create for this purpose.

```
class Thing {
    ...
    public function to_json() {
        return json_encode(array(
            'something' => $this->something,
            'protected_something' => $this->get_protected_something(),
            'private_something' => $this->get_private_something()                
        ));
    }
    ...
}
```

**[A more detailed writeup](http://jondavidjohn.com/show-non-public-members-with-json_encode/)**

Comment: json_encode() is just outputting "{}" when I pass it these objects.  It's not a matter of having my arrays be defined associative or not, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe he is talking about the $a->properties array, which looks like it contains the data you're after.  Because that is a private variable, it will be ignored by json_encode(), and cause json_encode() to output '{}' as you are describing.

Comment: I was hoping that json_encode() would be able to see exposed methods to define some sort of behavior involving objects without externally accessible properties.  It seems that this cannot yet be done, so I wrote up a function to recursively process these lists of objects, instead.

Comment: You can see another solution at http://jrgns.net/content/json-encode-ing-private-and-protected-properties

Comment: for completeness, as mentioned by @Jrgns, you can return `get_object_vars( $this );`  to dump all the properties.

Comment: implementing `JsonSerializable` is an elegant way to do this

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Private fields are according to the Encapsulation OOP principle so using JsonSerializable interface is the best way to solve the problem

Answer (score 49):

In PHP >= 5.4.0 there is a new interface for serializing objects to JSON : [JsonSerializable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)

Just implement the interface in your object and define a `JsonSerializable` method which will be called when you use `json_encode`.

So the **solution** for PHP >= 5.4.0 should look something like this:

```
class JsonObject implements JsonSerializable
{
    // properties

    // function called when encoded with json_encode
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: To echo the JSON array, return `json_encode($result)` where `$result = get_object_vars($this);`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - automatically works with any class as get_object_vars will iterate all the properties.

Comment: I'm not sure what has changed in PHP or my code, but no matter what I do lately  `get_object_vars($this)` disregards the scope of $this and refuses to introspect on the private members of object.  When all members are private, I get an empty array result.  I'm using PHP 5.6.31.

Is there some requirement for getting `get_object_vars($this)` to recognize scope?

Comment: I don't think anything changed for `get_object_vars`. It was always only returning properties which were accessible. Thus when calling from within an object you'll get all privates and from outside you don't. See http://php.net/get_object_vars#example-6296

Answer (score 5):

Following code worked for me:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

Comment: Emh. Maybe it's `json.encode(get_object_vars($this))`?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see this mentioned yet, but beans have a built-in method called `getProperties()`.

So, to use it:

```
// What bean do we want to get?
$type = 'book';
$id = 13;

// Load the bean
$post = R::load($type,$id);

// Get the properties
$props = $post->getProperties();

// Print the JSON-encoded value
print json_encode($props);
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "id": "13",
    "title": "Oliver Twist",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
}
```

Now take it a step further. If we have an array of beans...

```
// An array of beans (just an example)
$series = array($post,$post,$post);
```

...then we could do the following:

- Loop through the array with a `foreach` loop.
- Replace each element (a bean) with an array of the bean's properties.

So this...

```
foreach ($series as &$val) {
  $val = $val->getProperties();
}

print json_encode($series);
```

...outputs this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "13",
        "title": "Oliver Twist",
        "author": "Charles Dickens"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "title": "Oliver Twist",
        "author": "Charles Dickens"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "title": "Oliver Twist",
        "author": "Charles Dickens"
    }
]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I usually include a small function in my objects which allows me to dump to array or json or xml.  Something like:

```
public function exportObj($method = 'a')
{
     if($method == 'j')
     {
         return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
     }
     else
     {
         return get_object_vars($this);
     }
}
```

either way, `get_object_vars()` is probably useful to you.

Comment: I can just use

    json_encode($thing->export());

to give me the json I want, but that doesn't work as well when I've got arrays of them.

Comment: Then you can convert the array of objects into an array of arrays with something like `for each($objArray as $key => $obj){$arrArray[$key] = $obj->export());}  json_encode($arrArray);` or you could do an array_map with get_object_vars().

Answer (score 0):

```
$products=R::findAll('products');
$string = rtrim(implode(',', $products), ',');
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way:

```
function xml2array($xml_data)
{
    $xml_to_array = [];

    if(isset($xml_data))
    {
        if(is_iterable($xml_data))
        {
            foreach($xml_data as $key => $value)
            {
                if(is_object($value))
                {
                    if(empty((array)$value))
                    {
                        $value = (string)$value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $value = (array)$value;
                    }
                    $value = xml2array($value);
                }
                $xml_to_array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $xml_to_array = $xml_data;
        }
    }

    return $xml_to_array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for an array of objects, I used something like this, while following the custom method for php < 5.4:

```
$jsArray=array();

//transaction is an array of the class transaction
//which implements the method to_json

foreach($transactions as $tran)
{
    $jsArray[]=$tran->to_json();
}

echo json_encode($jsArray);
```