# Using PHP to run a query and place it in a javascript object

Tags: php, javascript, oracle

I am trying to run a stored procedure using PHP.  I want to put the results of the query into a javascript object.  I cannot find how to accomplish this.  I have run this code but I get one of the results I am returning is undefined.  Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("call sp_getGenre()");
    if($result === FALSE){
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                console.log(<? $row['Type'] ?>);
                var genreObj = new Object();
                genreObj.name = "<? echo $row['Type'] ?>";
                genreObj.level = <? echo $row['Level'] ?>;
    <?
                $parentID = $row['PrevID'];
                if($parent == null){ $parent = "0"; }
    ?>
                genreObj.parent = <? $parent ?>;
                arrGenre.push(genreObj);
            </script>
    <?
        }
    ?>
```

I am fairly new to the PHP world but would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste here the output, why you don't use echo or = to display variable content in genreObj.parent = <? $parent ?>;

You can easily create the object using Ajax

Comment: Thank you for teh fast replies.  I'm not fully understanding.  Can you give me an example of what genreObj.name = "<? echo $row['Type'] ?>"; should look like please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
<? $row['Type'] ?>
```

Should be

```
<?= $row['Type'] ?> or
<? echo $row['Type'] ?>
```

Same goes for

```
<? $parent ?>;
```

Comment: I added the echo and still get no results.  Firebug says one of the first returned value "bob" is undefined.

    genreObj.name = "<? echo $row['Type'] ?>";

Comment: You sure all of your PHP variables have values?

Comment: yes, I ran the stored procedure in HeidiSQL and saw all the results.

Comment: This did the trick I had to get rid of echo and just use ?=  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Build an associative array in PHP resembling the JavaScript object you want, then use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert it into a JSON object, you can then easily pass on to JavaScript.

You may even be able to do something like:

```
<?php
// stuff
$resultObj = json_encode($row);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var genreObj = <?= $resultObj ?>;
</script>
```

This is not supposed to be a perfect solution to your problem, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to build a PHP object and pass that object to a javascript object?

Comment: Not by default, your object class has to provide encoding methods. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697656/using-json-encode-on-objects-in-php-regardless-of-scope

Comment: Is using that method the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Code below is not fully tested but the basic Idea is to Write all values into an array, then convert that array to a json object.  From there assign the json object to the jsonresults variable.  Now you can pull up all the info you need via javascript.

```
<?php


$result = mysql_query("call sp_getGenre()");
if($result === FALSE){
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $resultsarray = array("type"=> $row['type'], "level" => $row['Level'}, "previd" => $row['PrevID']);
    $jsonifiedresults = json_encode($resultsarray);
    ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jsonresult = <? echo $jsonifiedresults; ?>;

                console.log(jsonresult.type);
                var genreObj = new Object();
                genreObj.name = jsonresult.type;
                genreObj.level = jsonresult.level;
                genreObj.parent = jsonreult.prevID;
                arrGenre.push(genreObj);
            </script>
<?php
        }
?>
```