# Convert CI_Model to JSON and then Send to AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, model

How to convert an object to JSON using json_encode and then send this JSON to AJAX as response?

**CI_Model :**

```
<?php

class TResponse extends CI_Model
{
    private $status;
    private $topics;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**Inside Controller :**

```
$response = new Model\TResponse ();
$response->status = true;
echo json_encode($response);
```

**AJAX :**

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
            $.ajax ({
                type : 'POST', // hide URL
                url : 'My_Controller/exec', // form validation file
                data : $('#myform').serialize (),
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function (data)
                {
                    console.log("ok");
                }
                , error: function(xhr, status, error)
                {
                    console.log(status+" "+error+" "+xhr)
                }
            });
```

**PROBLEM :**

When i execute that code result error. the error is "error Internal Server Error [Object object]". How to solve my problem?

Comment: that won't work: `$response->status = true;` because $status is declared private.

Comment: @jeff : i have tried to change it to public but still same error appear. other idea?

Comment: I have myself never tried to json_encode() a class object...

Comment: @jeff : or you have any idea how to parse 1 variable and 1 array from controller to ajax in same time ? because i want to parse 1 variable and 1 array in same time i make a new object to store it.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062824/convert-object-of-class-stdclass-to-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using `$response = new Model\TResponse();`. It not "the codeigniter way" to load a model. But I think it must be related to the problem because the code belows works perfectly for me.

Notice I have made both class properties public. Private properties are not exposed and so would not be "presented" to `json_encode()`.

```
class TResponse extends CI_Model
{
    public $status = FALSE;
    public $topics = ['php', 'stackoverflow', 'json'];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

In the controller

```
$this->load->model('TResponse');
$this->TResponse->status = TRUE;
echo json_encode($this->TResponse);
```

Your javascript is fine as is.

If I use this

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

This is what the console reports

```
Object
  status: true
  topics: Array[3]
    0: "php"
    1: "stackoverflow"
    2: "json"
    length: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode( $response ));
```

in the view

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('path/to_your_controller/function')?>",
            data: {some_data: val},
            success: function (data) {
                var options = '';
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                   // read data , each element of the JSON object
                });
             }
        });
```

Comment: Are we must not use dataType: "JSON"?

Comment: If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response