# convert stdClass Object in array or json, Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-cloud-functions, http-post, stdclass

I have an post request API that returns stdClass object as response.
I'm using firebase cloud function in Javascript and I tried to use response.json() but it gets error
"Converting circular structure to JSON" so I need to convert or do something on stdClass object to array or json. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you show the output?

Comment: I can't see the ouput cuz if I try .json() , it gets an error and if i just send response i get {"size":0,"timeout":0}

Comment: but from the documentation for this API output must be something like this..

Comment: [company] => stdClass Object(
            [testrentcar] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [trip] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [code] => 2
                                )

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062824/convert-object-of-class-stdclass-to-json-object/16063282