# Pulling records from database to javascript by Symfony2 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, symfony

Im trying to fetch categories list from my database and put it in my javascript code so i can use it later. But I've encountered problems with this task - after returning this list to javascript - they are empty.

Here is my symfony2 controller action code:

```
public function fetchCategoriesAction(){
     $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyDataBundle:Category')->findAll();
     $return=array("responseCode"=>200,  "categories"=>$categories);
     $return=json_encode($return);//jscon encode the array
     return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
}
```

Here is my js code:

var categories;

function categoriesLoad(){

```
var url=$("#categories_fetch").val(); //link to my controller

$.post(url,function(data){

     if(data.responseCode==200 ){           
         categories = data.categories;
         console.log(categories);
     }else{
       console.log("An unexpeded error occured.");
    }
});
```

}

I'm running 

`$(document).ready(function() {
    categoriesLoad();
});`

But then after using console.log(categories) I'm getting
empty objects, although their number match the number of records in the database.

I'm just starting programming in symfony2 and I'd appreciate any help :)

EDIT:

**SOLVED**

I've just changed my controller action code.
Here it is updated:

```
public function fetchCategoriesAction(){

    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $categories = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT u
            FROM MyDataBundle:Category u'
    )->getResult();

    $categories = $serializer->serialize($categories, 'json');
    $return=array("responseCode"=>200,  "categories"=>$categories);
    $return=json_encode($return);
    return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
}
```

Now it works fine.
Thanks to @Pawel and @SAM

Comment: Few tips, 1. Are you getting the $categories array in php side, 
2. if you are getting the value for $categories, then try to console.log(data);
3. define the categories : var categories = data.categories;
Let me know the result

Comment: @SAM 1. I've made test function before at php side and it contains variables it looks like this : public function testAction(){
  $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VelrezDataBundle:Category')->findAll();
  
  return new Response(var_dump( $categories ));
 }

Comment: can you tell me the status of 
2. if you are getting the value for $categories, then try to console.log(data);
So that i can get some clue by any chance

Comment: the output is like this:`array(5) { [0]=> object(Proj\DataBundle\Entity\Category)#333 (2) { ["name":"Proj\DataBundle\Entity\Category":private]=> string(8) "Test2" ["id":"Proj\DataBundle\Entity\Category":private]=> int(17) } [1]=> object(Proj\DataBundle\Entity\Category)#334 (2) { ["name":"Proj\DataBundle\Entity\Category":private]=> string(10) "Multimedia" ["id":"Proj\DataBundle\Entity\Category":private]=> int(15) }... } `

Comment: 2. After console.log(data) - the output is `[15:20:47.122] ({responseCode:200, categories:[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]})`

Comment: You have ready solution with json object in response in comment below.

Comment: There you are, dear, you are returning the object array, that will not be converted into normal array, try itterating the array in php itself and create a normal array, then the flow will work

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697656/using-json-encode-on-objects-in-php-regardless-of-scope

Comment: Ok, I've solved the problem using serializer. I'll paste solution right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My example:
PHP function:

```
public function getDistrictListAction($id) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
           // DQL
        );

        return new JsonResponse($query->getArrayResult());
    }
```

JS Code:

```
var dropdown = $('.dropdown-selector');
dropdown.change( function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: 'url_to_function'
         beforeSend: function() {
              dropdown.attr('disabled', true);
         },
         success: function(data) {
              dropdown.find('option').not('[value=]').remove();
              $.each( JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {
                   dropdown.append( $( "<option></option>" ).attr( "value", value.id ).text( value.name ));
              });
              dropdown.attr('disabled', false);
         }
    });
}
```

This you can set on change event for example as a callback. Before send you make dropdown disabled, and after load via AJAX option you are enabale it again.

Comment: Little tip; you don't have json_encode the result, you can just supply it to the constructor of JsonResponse directly. Also be sure you use a simple object or array persister before putting it into a json response or use getArrayResult().