# AJAX GET is not getting JSON encoded object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a JSON encoded object from a PHP file via AJAX GET using jQuery. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong. Here's my request in Javascript:

```
function getInfo()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax/ipGet.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }

    });
}
```

ajax/ipGet.php

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';


class ipInfo {
    private $ipAddress;
    private $status;
    private $serialNumber;
}

$ipInfo = new ipInfo;
$ipInfo->$ipAddress = "IP ADDRESS";
$ipInfo->$status = "ONLINE";
$ipInfo->$serialNumber = "TEST";

echo json_encode($ipInfo);

?>
```

I used GET because the user doesn't need to be redirected eventually. The PHP file will eventually retrieve values from a database.

Comment: Look at what comes back from the server, use your debugger.

Comment: First thing that stands out: if you're going to be accessing those class variables from outside the class like that, they need to be `public`, not `private`.  Not sure if that's your problem, but it's certainly an issue.

Comment: take a look at this question: [Using json_encode on objects in PHP (regardless of scope)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697656/using-json-encode-on-objects-in-php-regardless-of-scope)

Comment: @epascarello, thanks, but I just get blank in my console. Also, I changed the private to public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change those `private` variables to `public`.
2. Before you call `echo` at the end, call `header('Content-Type: application/json');`
3. You might need to add `accepts: 'application/json'` to your `$.ajax` call.

**Edit:**

Also, remove the second set of `$` in each line that you access the object variables.  See below:

```
$ipInfo->$ipAddress = "IP ADDRESS";
$ipInfo->$status = "ONLINE";
$ipInfo->$serialNumber = "TEST";
```

should be

```
$ipInfo->ipAddress = "IP ADDRESS";
$ipInfo->status = "ONLINE";
$ipInfo->serialNumber = "TEST";
```

Comment: `dataType: "json"` forces `$.ajax()` to interpret the result as JSON, regardless of the `Content-type` header.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't receive anything in my console. The Network also shows a 200 OK on `ipGet.php`.

Comment: @Carpetfizz I've noticed another bug in your PHP code and edited my answer to describe it.  Give that a shot and let me know how it goes!

Comment: +1 for the edit; that's an easy mistake to make, and I think is the actual issue.  For an explanation @Carpetfizz, PHP is trying to retrieve the value of `$ipAddress` (which is `''`) and set a nonexistent attribute on the `$ipInfo` object.  So `json_encode()` on an empty object is probably encoding nothing to nothing, assuming it isn't erroring out before that.