# json_encode() returns an empty value

Tags: php, json

I have a User object and I want to encode it to a JSON format, but `json_encode()` returns an empty value `"{}"`. What I am doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once 'DataBase.php';
include_once '../Model/User.php';
$user = DataBase::getUser('username', $_GET['q']); //getting User object
$json = json_encode($user); //returns "{}"
echo $json;
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($json);` and see what happens.

Comment: I meant `var_dump($user)`

Comment: `DataBase::getUser` is not returning a valid user object

Comment: @Adelphia, var_dump returns display User object with properties, which I fetched from database.

Comment: pls show us the var_dump

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The properties of the User object were private. All I need is to created to_json() method in a User class.

Comment: You should accept your own answer when you're able to and unmark the other answer as accepted - since the other answer didn't solve your problem at all.

Comment: I was able to slove my problem, only because Roman Sokolovskyy has provided a link to a similar issue. Should I mark both answers ?

Answer (score -3):

I think because `$user = DataBase::getUser('username', $_GET['q']);` returns an object, not array

[Using json_encode on objects in PHP (regardless of scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697656/using-json-encode-on-objects-in-php-regardless-of-scope)

Comment: There is no problem encoding objects with `json_encode`.  Try `php -r "$a=new stdclass(); $a->b=1; echo json_encode($a);"`  It will output `{"b":1}` as expected.

Comment: Yes, it returns a User object.